# Jenkins File Viewer

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I'm in the process of setting up our builds on our new Jenkins CI server. One thing I've noticed, which I don't really like is that I can't see a difference in the changes.

Jenkins knows what files have been modified/deleted but I cannot see where I can see the diff of those files?

Comment: Changes to the job? Or changes to the project being built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins does not calculate diffs itself, but instead lets you link to a tool that does, such as a diff on GitHub, or a ViewSVN instance etc.

For example, on Apache's Jenkins instance, you can see a "ViewSVN" link next to each change:
https://builds.apache.org/job/ActiveMQ/changes

It depends on your SCM and the tool you normally use for browsing diffs, but there should be a Jenkins [plugin available](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) for you.

If not, it should be trivial to write your own :)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's trivial to write your own Jenkins plugin, but it's definitely possible if none already exists.

Comment: I agree there's a learning curve to a Jenkins plugin in general, but this type of plugin is extremely simple and has a number of implementations that could be essentially copied :)